# List "kubectl top pods" filtered by node

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to get `top pods` filtered by node?

Use case: I have a node which is reported to use 103% of the cpu and I want to validate which pods are causing it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is direct way to do it with `kubectl top pods` command since the only option to filter is label/selector which apply to pod only.

For your use case, you can use the command:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide | grep <node> | awk {'print $1'} | xargs -n1 command kubectl top pods  --no-headers
```

- `kubectl get pods -o wide`: display pods with their associated node information
- `grep <node>`: let you filter pod located on a specific node
- `awk {'print $1'}`: print the first column (name of the pods)
- `xargs -n1 command kubectl top pods --no-headers`: execute the top command for each pod without the headers (NAME, CPU, MEMORY)

Additionally, you can check the limits you've set for each pod in one specific node using the command `kubectl describe node <node>`

Comment: Note the command above uses the default namespace and does not sort the result by either of CPU/memory usage. This can be tweaked as `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide | grep <node_name> | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | xargs -n2 kubectl top pods --no-headers --namespace | sort -t ' ' --key 2 --numeric --reverse` where using `--key 2` or `--key 3` sorts by CPU or memory respectively

Comment: Just one addendum to @DanielJ.G. 's great comment:
`-t ' '`was counterproductive for me in the sort.
Leaving it out fixed sorting by memory (key 3)

Answer (score 0):

For powershell users, just set your **<node_name>** to filter

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | sls "<node_name>" | ForEach-Object {$row = ($_ -split "\s+"); $top = ("kubectl -n $($row[0]) top pod $($row[1]) --no-headers --containers" | iex); foreach($line in $top){$container=$line -split "\s+"; [pscustomobject]@{node=$nodeName; pod=$container[0];container=$container[1];cpu=$container[2];memory=$container[3]}} } | Sort-Object pod| ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with this command and I can't seem to figure it out:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to short the number of request to K8s API to 3 (vs the number of pods):

```
LABELS='key=value'
kubectl top pods --no-headers -A --sort-by=cpu | \
  grep -f <(kubectl get pod -A --no-headers -o wide | \
  grep -f <(kubectl get nodes -l ${LABELS} -oname | sed -e 's|^node/||') | awk '{print $2}')
```

With labels like `key=value` you filtered the nodes you'd like to see CPU usage for. The details are [here](https://gist.github.com/aws-simple/78a4618cdb836e195f85ae2b8419780d).

Answer (score 0):

For nicely formatted like you are used from kubectl:

```
NODE_NAME=<node_name>
printf "%-30s %-60s %-10s %-10s\n" "NAMESPACE" "POD" "CPU(m)" "MEMORY(Mi)" && kubectl get pods -A --field-selector spec.nodeName=$NODE_NAME | awk '$2 != "NAME" {print $1,$2}' | xargs -n2 bash -c 'ns=$0; pod=$1; echo $(kubectl top pod $pod -n $ns --no-headers) | awk -v ns=$ns -v pod=$pod '\''{printf "%-30s %-60s %-10s %-10s\n", ns, pod, $2, $3}'\'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).